# Taking a crack at project euler problem 3, is my solution correct?

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization

Problem 3 of Project Euler reads as follows:

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
>   What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

I've made this solution, makes sense, looks okay, works for small numbers but when we get to the problem's huge number is when the program runs forever. My question is, is this fundamentally correct, and if so how could i optimize the code? In my understanding, the problematic function is is_prime().

```
bool is_factor(long long int num, long long int factor)
{
    if(!(num%factor))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool is_prime(long long int num)
{
    long long int i;
    bool flag = true;
    for(i = 2; i <= num/2; i++)
    {
        if(!(num%i))
        {
            flag = false;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}

int main(void)
{
    long long int i, max_factor = 1;
    for(i = 1; i < 600851475143; i++)
    {
        if(is_factor(600851475143,i) && is_prime(i) && i>max_factor)
        {
            max_factor = i;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",max_factor);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe the right place for such questions is [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @HristoIliev Not if the validity of the code is in question.

Comment: You should probably learn about [*dynamic programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). You do a lot of calculations many many times. If the result of those calculations could be "cached" or "remembered" you don't need to calculate them again, making the program more effective.

Comment: Note how in `is_prime` you keep looping even once you know it's not prime. `return false` in the loop in place of `flag = false` will be much faster. You can also check to the square root of `num` instead of `num/2`, which is *much* faster for larger numbers.

Comment: For reference, here's what I used when I solved this. It's bad, has a few ugly edge cases, and was never meant to see the light of day, but oh well. https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/56bf2dd9e1d5af780b2fc61bb98ffeb2

Comment: Just counting to 600 billion will take forever. So you need an entirely different approach. Starting from 600851475143 and working backwards would be a minor improvement. After all, you *are* looking for the *largest* prime factor. But the real solution requires that you think about how the math works. I'll give a couple examples.  A) 14=2*7.  B) 220=2*110 and 110=2*55 and 55=5*11.

Comment: You need to learn group theory to be able to solve this in realistic time.  Also, you should read about memoization  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ah, yes, I know how to implement a couple of dynamic structures, such as binary trees and such, but I've never actually used them to cache anything. I will certainly look into it though. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @everyone The solution to this problem is literally five lines of C code. You don't need dynamic programming, memoization, or group theory (rofl). You don't even need a list of primes or an `is_prime` function.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks for the tips, i'll be sure to try them. I'll look at your answer after i've solved this though.

Comment: @user3386109 Although I appreciate learning the underlying math and solutions, it is not practical to learn a whole branch of mathematics for problem #3 (not just yet anyway), but I think i'll encounter it in uni and i feel good about that. I'll try to figure out your hints.

Comment: @DuckHunterZx My whole point is that you **don't** need to learn any mathematics that you don't already know. That's why I'm laughing at the absurd notion that you need to know group theory to solve this. You also **don't** need to know any advanced programming techniques like dynamic programming or memoization. This is Euler #3 after all. **The hints contain the answer.** (Note: Ignore the part about counting backwards. That was just an optimization for your current solution. Counting backwards is not part of the actual solution.)

Comment: @DuckHunterZx It's basically the same idea as yours just with a few tweaks to speed up prime finding

Comment: @Carcigenicate You do not need an `is_prime` function, or a list of primes, to solve this problem.

Comment: @user3386109 Well, you need to know if a number is prime or not, so at the very least you need the same code that would be contained in a theoretical `is_prime` function. Whether or not you break that code off into its own function though is a matter of taste, and idk if I'd be encouraging people to avoid making their code modular; even if it isn't necessary here.

Comment: @Carcigenicate The smallest factor of a number **is** a prime. You don't need to check if it is a prime.

Comment: @user3386109 The problem is finding the largest prime factor. How would knowing that the smallest factor is prime help?

Comment: @Carcigenicate How I solved it is when a "small" factor is found then divide the large value by that factor. As the factors get larger the value gets smaller and when they meet what is left is the largest factor. [This code finds the answer in the blink of an eye.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17ebac9bac81e4bc)

Comment: @Carcigenicate Take 14 for example. The smallest factor of 14 must be less than or equal to `floor(sqrt(14) ) = 3`. And in fact the smallest factor of 14 is 2. Divide 14 by 2 to get 7. The smallest factor of 7 must be less than or equal to `floor(sqrt(7)) = 2`. But 7 doesn't have any factors <= 2, so 7 is the answer.

Comment: @user3386109 Ya, I just looked up solutions to find an explanation. Ya, that would be more efficient.

Comment: @user3386109 alright great, going to eat, and brb to try this out, thank you lots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general strategy you're using so far, at a high level, looks like this:

1. Try dividing the target number by all numbers less than or equal to half the target number.
2. Each time you find a divisor, see if it's a prime number and bigger than the maximum factor. If so, update the maximum factor.
3. Return the largest number you find this way.

Considering that your goal is to find the largest factor of a single number, this is a fairly reasonable strategy. There are a couple of ways that you could speed this up. Some of them are echoed in the comments, while others (to the best of my knowledge) haven't been proposed there.

## Optimization 1: Eliminate the Primality Checking

Right now, you're proceeding by dividing the target number by each possible divisor, then checking whether those divisors are prime numbers. If your target number has a lot of divisors, then you're going to spend a lot of time checking divisors that aren't prime, which will eat into your runtime.

An alternative approach would be the following. As before, try dividing the target number by each possible divisor, in order. However, make one change: whenever you find a divisor, modify the target number by dividing out as many copies of that divisor as possible. If you do this, something interesting happens: the only numbers that you'll discover divide the number will be prime numbers.

Why is this?

To see why, think about how this will work. You'll first test whether 2 divides the number. If so, you'll divide out as many copies of 2 as is possible, meaning that if you try dividing by any number that's a multiple of 2 later on, you'll find that the larger number isn't a divisor.

Similarly, you'll then test whether 3 divides the number. If so, you'll divide out all the copies of 3, so no number that is a multiple of three will ever divide the remaining number.

This single change eliminates the need for the `is_prime` function, saving a ton of work. Plus, you can be guaranteed that any divisor you find this way will be a prime number.

## Optimization 2: Stopping Early

Your current code works by stopping the search for divisors as soon as the candidate divisor is greater than half the target number. If you're looking for divisors in general, this is the best that you can do. However, if you begin by making the above optimization, you can stop even earlier than this.

The above strategy of cleanly dividing out all prime factors you encounter has an added benefit. Suppose that, after all the dividing that's been done, your remaining target number is `n`. Now, imagine that your current divisor is `d` and that `d` < `n`. If `d` divides `n`, then you can write `n` as the product of the two numbers `d` and `n / d`. Because you've been dividing the target number through by all prime factors you encounter, we're guaranteed that `n` has no prime factors less than `d`. That means, in turn, that if `n / d` < `d`, then `d` can't be a divisor of `n`. Why? Because, if `d` did divide `n`, then the number `n / d` would have to have a prime factor less than `d`, but we know that `n` has no such prime factors.

As a result, as you're trying out divisors, you can stop as soon as `n / d` < `d`, or, equivalently, as soon as `n` < `d`<sup>2</sup>. Once that happens, you know that `n` no longer has any prime factors less than itself, so the leftover number `n` is the last prime divisor.

In practice, this will dramatically speed things up. Your target number is roughly 10<sup>12</sup>, and you can stop as soon as the last divisor is roughly on the order of the square root of that number, which is around 10<sup>6</sup>. That means you only need to search a million divisors, not a trillion!

## Optimization 3: Choose Divisors Intelligently

The two above optimizations, which more or less reflect your original strategy, will likely be enough for you to get your answer and call it a day. However, if you'd like to speed things up a bit more just for the fun of it, you could consider trying to select your divisors a bit better.

Right now, for example, half of the numbers you try dividing the target by are even. Aside from 2, no even number is prime, so you could consider splitting your loop into two pieces: a special-case to handle 2, and a loop that starts counting at 3 and takes steps of size 2 (3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, etc.) rather than steps of size 1. (Eyeballing the target number, you can see that it's not even, so you could even skip division by 2 entirely!)

Even better, consider downloading a list of all the prime numbers up to approximately 10<sup>7</sup>. Either hardcode that list into your program, or dump it all into a text file and read it in at program startup. Then, only divide the target by the numbers on that list. Voila! You're now only dividing by prime numbers, saving you a lot of time and effort. (The Prime Number Theorem says that only about ln 10<sup>7</sup> ≈ 18.4 numbers less than 10<sup>7</sup> will be prime, so that's likely going to give you an extra 20x speedup on top of everything else.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Holy cow, you're the man, this was the most complete and detailed answer. I think what helped me most is how you shifted the focus of the problem from optimizing the primality test to removing it completely. Even after the first optimization it took no longer than 0.005s so i am thoroughly impressed, never got to witness that drastic a difference. I will call it a night right now as it worked, and will come back tomorrow to take a detailed look at your other proposals which are definitely interesting. Thanks for your insights!

Comment: There is a flaw lurking in this description. It says to divide out all the instances of the current test divisor `d`, and eventually return the leftover number `n`. However, if there are multiple instances of the last (largest) prime factor, and we continue while `d*d <= n`, this will result in dividing them all out, leaving `n` set to 1.

Comment: Ah, good point. That can be special-cased away. Thanks for spotting that!