# Given a number N and an array A. Check if N can be expressed as a product of one or more array elements

Tags: algorithm, math

Given a number `N (where N <= 10^18)` and an array `A(consisting of at most 20 elements)`. I have to tell if it is possible to form `N` by multiplying some elements of the array. Note that, I can use any element multiple times.

Example: `N = 8` and `A = {2, 3}`. Here, `8 = 2 * 2 * 2`. So the answer is `YES`. But if `N = 15`, then I can't form 15 as a product of one or more elements using them any number of times. So in this case the answer is `NO`.

How can I approach this problem?

Comment: Start by dividing N by each element of A. If an element of A doesn't divide evenly into N, then you can discard that element. Consider `N = 15` and `A = {2, 3}`. Since 2 doesn't divide evenly into 15, it can be discarded.

Comment: @user3386109 If N = 12 and A = {2, 6}. In that case your approach shows wrong answer.

Comment: @YaseenMollik Your comment makes little sense. All numbers which are not divisors of `N` can be deleted from `A` without affecting the answer. `N = 12` and `A = {2,6}` is not a counterexample to that relatively obvious point. In that case, nothing is deleted from `A`

Comment: @JohnColeman I misunderstood that. I kept dividing N by some element until it is no longer divisible by that element. I missed the point.

Comment: This is best thought of as a preprocessing step. Before you do anything else, trim `A` down to a set that you can actually use.

Comment: I agree with Rory's answer that the next step is to factor N and all of the elements of A. [Here's a recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56672944) that deals with factoring small numbers. I would sort A and then factor each one starting from the smallest. Each factor of an element of A is definitely a factor of N, and will often be a factor of other elements of A.

Comment: I would start by factoring the elements of `A`. Either that will give you the factorization of `N` almost for free, or the problem has no solution.

Comment: One final hint: elements of A that are greater than `sqrt(N)` are special. At most one such element can be used. Consider N = 1800 and A = {45, 50, 72, ...}. Since `sqrt(1800) = 42`, at most one of those three elements can be used.

Comment: There is a classic algorithm solution for this. You can make Queues for each elements present in your array and keep on populating them until you find your element. Search for solution of this problem and the approach shall be the same for your question as well: `Find kth multiple of given numbers. For eg, if numbers are 2,3,4,5 then find 6th number divisible by all 2,3,4,5` Let me know if you are not able to solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple pseudocode:

```
A_divisors = set()
for x in A:
    if num % x == 0:
        A_divisors.add(x)

candidates = A_divisors.clone()
seen = set()

while(candidates.size()):
    size = divisors.size()
    new_candidates = set()
    for y in candidates:
        for x in A_divisors:
            if num % (x * y) == 0 and (x * y) not in seen:
                new_candidates.add(x * y)
                seen.add(x * y)
            if x * y == num:
                return true
    candidates = new_candidates

return false
```

Complexity: O(|A| * k * log k), with k being amount of divisors. The log k would be the cost of adding and checking if element is present in the set. With a hash based approach it would be O(1) and can be removed. I am also assuming %, * operations to be O(1).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195886/discussion-on-answer-by-juvian-given-a-number-n-and-an-array-a-check-if-n-can-b).

Answer (score 2):

Since you show no code or algorithm, I'll just give one idea. If you want more help, please show more of your own work on the problem.

Note that `N` can be at most `60` bits long. This is small enough that `N` could be decomposed into its prime factors pretty quickly. So first work up a good factoring algorithm for numbers of that size.

Your algorithm would factor `N` and each of the elements in your array `A`. If there is any prime factor of `N` that does not divide into any element of `A` then your answer is `NO`. This is the case in your example of `N = 15`.

Now you work with the prime factors and their exponents in `N` and in the elements of `A`. Now you want to find a subset (or, more properly, a sub-multiset) of `A` where the exponents for each prime add up to that in `N`. This greatly reduces the sizes of your numbers thus makes the problem easier.

That last part is not trivial. Work more on this problem and show us some of your work, then we can continue helping you.

Comment: Good answer (+1) -- but you aren't looking for a *subset* of `A` so much as a sub-multiset. A slightly different perspective: given the factorizations of `N` and the elements of `A`, replace each number by a vector of exponents (including zeros as placemarkers for missing prime factors). Then the problem is one of expressing the target vector as a linear combination of the other vectors, using nonnegative integers as coefficients.

Comment: @JohnColeman: You are right about the multiset--I should have used that terminology. I'll try to change that soon to be more clear. I did think in terms of the vectors but I was keeping that for later, after the questioner shows more of his own work. I'm still working on keeping a good balance for questions that need to show more by the questioner, but I think leaving the vectors for later was a good choice for me.

Comment: It is hard to strike a balance between giving a useful hint and doing someone`s homework for them, especially in a case like this where the question is fairly interesting.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow below approach:

1. Form 2 queues: `Q2` and `Q3`.
2. Add 2 in `Q2` and 3 in `Q3`.
3. Get the minimum of the head of both queues, lets say `h`. Remove `h` from the corresponding queue. Check if it is equal to the number `N`. If yes, return true. If it is greater than `N`, return false.
4. If it is less than `N`, then add `2*h` in `Q2` and `3*h` in `Q3`. Repeat steps 3 to 4.

Please note that when the minimum `h` comes from `Q3`, you need not to add `2*h` into `Q2`. That is because you already have added that element in `Q3` before. (I will leave it for you to deduce}. Keep on doing this procedure until your `h` is greater than `N`.

If you have more such numbers, you can form there queues as well. I think this is an optimal solution in case you have more numbers to process.

Can you guess the time and space complexity of this?